# Initramfs not reading new configuration/scripts

Tags: initramfs, initrd

I am trying to add some custom initramfs scripts to `/etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-bottom/`. However, these are not executed at next boot, after having rebuilt with

```
# update-initramfs -u
```

In fact, if I get an initramfs shell by booting with kernel parameter `break=bottom`, they are not even present in `/scripts/init-bottom`, nor are any edits that I tried to make to configurations files in `/etc/initramfs-tools/`, which I checked inside initramfs in `/conf`.

What am I doing wrong? How can I get `update-initramfs -u` to read my new configurations/scripts?